# hacer que un dato repetido de una lista solo se repita una vez

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

buenas ocupo saber como hacer que un dato que se repita muchas veces en una list solo salga una vez en una nueva lista.
esoy haciendo una seleccion de ubicacion por provincia, cantones o condados , distritos y barrios

por ejemplo

| idProvincia | provincia | idCanton | Canton | idDistrito | Distrito | idBarrio | Barrio o Comunidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | San José | 1 | San José | 1 | Carmen | 1 | San José |
| 1 | San José | 1 | San José | 1 | Carmen | 2 | Amón |
| 1 | San José | 1 | San José | 2 | Merced | 1 | San José(parte) |
| 1 | San José | 1 | San José | 2 | Merced | 2 | Claret |
| 2 | Alajuela | 1 | Alajuela | 1 | Alajuela | 1 | Alajuela |
| 2 | Alajuela | 1 | Alajuela | 2 | San Ramon | 1 | San Ramón |

y asi sucesivamente hasta cumplir con todos los item como se ve en el inicio san josé sale mas de una vez pero ocupo que a la hora de meterlo en un comboBox solo me aparezca una vez san jose en la parte de provincia y así
trate de usar el List.Contains() pero me marca error a la hora de dividir la tabla

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a crear un diccionario intermedio. Es decir, antes de mostrar la lista añade al diccionario todos los elementos siempre que no existan ya en el diccionario y muestra el diccionario.

Por ejemplo (escribo de memoria):

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetUniqueValues(List<string> values)
{
   Dictionary<string, string> uniqueValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   foreach (string value in values)
      if (!uniqueValues.Contains(value))
         uniqueValues.Add(value, value);
   return uniqueValues;
}
```

En este método `values` sería la lista de cadena que quieres obtener.

Ten en cuenta que el resultado de este método es un diccionario, si quieres obtener los valores puedes reconvertirlo en una lista:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> unique in uniqueValues)
    values.Add(unique.Value);
```